# Specific positioning problem with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get to the result from below using Flexbox

[image: Desired rendering]

But I find it difficult to position my 2 blocks on the right, one of the blocks crosses the line and I cannot make it go up.

I need this to be managed dynamically afterwards, this is the reason why I don't use CSS Grid.

Am I doing it the wrong way?

```css
 .o-wrapper{
        padding-right: 1.875rem;
        padding-left: 1.875rem;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 75rem;
    }
    .page__project{
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .page__projects-list{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .page__project-bloc{
        padding: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .page__project--small{
          width: 31.0526315789%;
          height: 177px;
    }

    .page__project--large{
          width: 65%;
          height: 177px;
    }

    .page__project--big{
          width: 65%;
          height: 370px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="o-wrapper page__projects-list">
        <div class="page__project page__project--small">
          <div class="page__project-bloc page__project-bloc--small">
            <h3 role="heading" aria-level="3">VLW #48</h3>
            <p>
              Mise en page du magazine Vivre la Wallonie 48e édition.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page__project page__project--large">
          <div class="page__project-bloc page__project-bloc--small">
            <h3 role="heading" aria-level="3">Elit Ligula Etiam</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque
              nisl consectetur et.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page__project page__project--big">
          <div class="page__project-bloc page__project-bloc--big">
            <h3 role="heading" aria-level="3">VLW #48</h3>
            <p>
              Mise en page du magazine Vivre la Wallonie 48e édition.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page__project page__project--small">
          <div class="page__project-bloc page__project-bloc--small">
            <h3 role="heading" aria-level="3">VLW #48</h3>
            <p>
              Mise en page du magazine Vivre la Wallonie 48e édition.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page__project page__project--small">
          <div class="page__project-bloc page__project-bloc--small">
            <h3 role="heading" aria-level="3">VLW #48</h3>
            <p>
              Mise en page du magazine Vivre la Wallonie 48e édition.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is a masonry layout, which flexbox cannot do (not in the sense you intend it to work). An option is to put those two divs on the bottom right into a single flex child.

Comment: What do you mean by 'managed dynamically'? I think a grid would make this a lot easier and I'm trying to understand why that wouldn't work.

Comment: I mean that the grid can very well start with a small block then a larger one and that in any direction. For now it's static, but it's only temporary. You think I could handle this problem with CSS GRID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it via flex, then I have this option you could fiddle with.

Otherwise I suggest you work with grid.

[Example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/liam88/pen/jOmOdRx)

I have created a container, with a row and making use of a sub row to manage the two small boxes. In the rows each image is an item. You can just switch out classes, images etc. as you need.

The aim is to treat those two as an item on its own.

##### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item short thin">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/600x600">
    </div>
    <div class="item short wide">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1800x600">
    </div>
    <div class="item large">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/600x600">
    </div>
    <div class="sub-row">
      <div class="item short">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/600x600">
      </div>
      <div class="item short">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/600x600">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### CSS

```css
.container{
    width:767px;
    padding:50px;
}
.row{
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.sub-row{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width:33%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.thin{
    width:33%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.wide{
    width:65%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.short{
    height:177px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.large{
    height:370px;
    width:65%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.row .item img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a textbook example question for a grid based solution. You can (easier) achieve this with `display: grid` and dividing your squares to a certain grid. [Read more about grid at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid).

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

will show the specified columns and rows. Then you provide the `grid-area` for each `div`.

```css
grid-column-gap: 5px;
grid-row-gap: 5px;
```

will show the space between each box. See this small example on how it looks like:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 3;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.box {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box div1">1</div>
  <div class="box div2">2</div>
  <div class="box div3">3</div>
  <div class="box div4">4</div>
  <div class="box div5">5</div>
</div>
```